# Rails 4 Custom Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my custom validator. I have a model `Price`, which looks like this:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  validates :from_days, :to_days, :netto_price, presence: true, numericality: true
  validate :days_range_validation

  private

  def days_range_validation
    unless to_days > from_days 
      errors[:to_days] << I18n.t('price.must_be_greater')
    end
  end
end
```

And the problem is that when I leave `to_days` and `from_days` blank in my form, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass
```

And now the goal is to use this validator only when `from_days` and `to_days` are present, but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `:if` option:

```
validate :days_range_validation, :if => :days_ranges_present?

# ...
private

def days_ranges_present?
  to_days.present? && from_days.present?
end
```